# exclude rows from table

Tags: arcpy, cursor

I am new to arcpy, and I am trying to write a code in order to extract just the records containing specific attributes.
This code gives back an empty table. What am I doing wrong?

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = 'C:/work'
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
fc = 'rbh.shp'
exclude = ["02-R00-04-B$0$210", "02-R16-04-B$0$210", "02-R00-04-B$0$220", "02-R16-04-B$0$220", "02-R00-04-B$0$211", "02-R16-04-B$0$211", "02-R00-04-B$0$320", "02-R16-04-B$0$320"]
with arcpy.UpdateCursor(fc, "Layer") as rows:
    for row in rows:
        if row not in exclude:
            rows.deleteRow()
```

Comment: by extract you mean you want to select a table by its attributes and thern export those selected features to new shapefile?

Comment: also what is the fieldname you're performing the select on

Comment: Exactly. I need to do Select by Attribute with arcpy and overwrite the initial shapefile. The field is called "Layer"...

Comment: Deleting rows is an expensive process, and if you mess up the query, you destroy data. Best practice is to select the rows you want to keep, and copy them to a new feature class.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding index to row (`row[0]`):

```
with arcpy.UpdateCursor(fc, "Layer") as rows:
    for row in rows:
        if row[0] not in exclude:
            rows.deleteRow()
```

Otherwise you are comparing a tuple: `('hello')` to strings: `'hello'` which will never match = all rows are deleted

Example in python console:

```
a = ('a',)
b = ['a','b']
a in b
False
a[0] in b
True
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try the code below, be sure to update the `out_path` variable and specify a folder location not filegeodatabase.

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = 'C:/work'
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
fc = 'rbh.shp'
feat_lyr = 'rbh_layer'
out_path = r"path\to\output folder\"
whereSQL = """ Layer <> '02-R00-04-B$0$210' OR Layer <> '02-R16-04-B$0$210' OR  Layer <> '02-R00-04-B$0$220' OR Layer <> '02-R16-04-B$0$220' OR Layer <> '02-R00-04-B$0$211' OR Layer <> '02-R16-04-B$0$211' OR Layer <> '02-R00-04-B$0$320' OR Layer <> '02-R16-04-B$0$320'"""
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(FC, feat_lyr)
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(feat_lyr, "NEW_SELECTION", whereSQL)

arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(feat_lyr,out_path, "Layer_Selection.shp")
```

Comment: thats a solution, I thought that selecting features then performing FCtoFC would only export the selection.

Comment: Thank you guys. I tried out your suggestions, but it still gives me tracebacks.

Comment: Runtime error  Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>   File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.6\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 7726, in SelectLayerByAttribute     raise e ExecuteError: The value cannot be a feature class ERROR 000840: The value is not a Raster Layer. ERROR 000840: The value is not a Mosaic Layer.

Comment: updated code to include, you're correct the select needs to eb executed on a layer not fc/shp

Comment: Try `whereSQL = """{0} NOT IN('02-R00-04-B$0$210','02-R16-04-B$0$210','02-R00-04-B$0$220','02-R16-04-B$0$220','02-R00-04-B$0$211','02-R16-04-B$0$211','02-R00-04-B$0$320','02-R16-04-B$0$320')""".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(feat_lyr,"Layer"))`

Comment: Why not Select_analysis rather than MakeFeatureLayer/SelectByAttribute/CopyFeatures?

Comment: So you don't have all the quotes to keep track you you could do something like this using your exclude list: 

exclude = ["'%s'"%x for x in exclude] 

"{0} NOT in ({1})".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(feat_lyr,"Layer"),",".join(exclude))

Answer (score 0):

as PolyGeo♦ 13  mentioned the [Select_analysis](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/select.htm) is a more efficient way to accomplish this task.

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = 'C:/work'
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

infeatures = 'fbh.shp'
outfeatures = r"path\to\output.shp"

whereSQL = """ Layer <> '02-R00-04-B$0$210' OR Layer <> '02-R16-04-B$0$210' OR  Layer <> '02-R00-04-B$0$220' OR Layer <> '02-R16-04-B$0$220' OR Layer <> '02-R00-04-B$0$211' OR Layer <> '02-R16-04-B$0$211' OR Layer <> '02-R00-04-B$0$320' OR Layer <> '02-R16-04-B$0$320'"""


arcpy.Select_analysis(infeatures, outfeatures, whereSQL)
```